# BIGQUERY: Replace a 'null' result from one table with a user id from another table

Tags: sql, timestamp, google-bigquery

trusty BQ experts.

**Background:**
I have users reading articles on a website (User Table A) and users clicking through to articles from an email (User Table B) and have BQ view tables for each user set. User Table A is missing some user_id of the users who have clicked through from the emails. See User Table A below.

```
*User Table A* - Website

id  | user_id    | article id  | viewed_at
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1          | 1000        | 2019-01-25 01:04:00 UTC
2   | 2          | 1001        | 2019-01-25 01:03:00 UTC
3   | 3          | 1002        | 2019-01-25 01:03:00 UTC
4   | null       | 1001        | 2019-01-25 01:04:00 UTC
5   | null       | 1000        | 2019-01-24 20:49:00 UTC
6   | null       | 1003        | 2019-01-24 20:47:00 UTC


*User Table B* - Email

id  | user_id    | article id  | clicked_at
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1          | 1000        | 2019-01-25 01:04:00 UTC
2   | 1          | 1000        | 2019-01-24 20:49:00 UTC
3   | 6          | 1003        | 2019-01-24 20:47:00 UTC
```

- I'm want to create a single view/table which replaces a null user_id result in User Table A with the user_id from User Table B **IF** the viewed_at and clicked_at are the same **AND** the article_id from User Table A and User Table B are also the same.
- I also want to retain the user_id null result if the corresponding viewed_at/clicked_at and article_id are not found in User Table B.

```
*Desired Result Table*

id  | user_id    | article id  | viewed_at
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1          | 1000        | 2019-01-25 01:04:00 UTC
2   | 2          | 1001        | 2019-01-25 01:03:00 UTC
3   | 3          | 1002        | 2019-01-25 01:03:00 UTC
4   | null       | 1001        | 2019-01-25 01:04:00 UTC
5   | 1          | 1000        | 2019-01-24 20:49:00 UTC
6   | 6          | 1003        | 2019-01-24 20:47:00 UTC
```

I hope this makes sense.

Please help. This has been doing my head in for months.

Comment: @mikhail you've been so helpful in the past, do you have any thoughts on this one?

Comment: Thanks, @gordonlinoff you're so helpful. I do have one questions though. I ran your query against a single article, which has a total read count (on the website) of 6,251. I would assume this total read count number should not change if I'm only replacing the 'null' values with a corresponding user_id (if it exists). 

When I run both your queries (which gives the same result as Mikail's query) I get a total article read count result of 21,109. 

Would you know why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a.id,
  IFNULL(a.user_id, b.user_id) user_id,
  a.article_id,
  viewed_at
FROM `project.dataset.website` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.email` b
ON a.user_id IS NULL
AND a.article_id = b.article_id
AND viewed_at = clicked_at
```

Comment: Thanks, @mikhail you're so helpful. I do have one questions though. I ran your query against a single article, which has a total read count (on the website) of 6,251. I would assume this total read count number should not change if I'm only replacing the 'null' values with a corresponding user_id (if it exists). 

When I run both your queries (which gives the same result as Gordon's query) I get a total article read count result of 21,109. 

Would you know why this might be occurring?

Comment: I would expect this because there is no any logic that prevents same row in Table A with NULL to match to multiple rows in Table B with same article and data thus increase in number of rows in result. you need to come up with business logic that would address this and ask post question. your current question as it is - is answered

Comment: Thanks @mikhail. I am able to query for the distinct user_id's which does help with another problem of mine so that you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `left join`:

```
select w.id,
       coalesce(w.user_id, e.user_id) as user_id,
       w.article_id, w.viewed_at
from website w left join
     email e
     on w.article_id = e.article_id and
        w.viewed_at = e.viewed_at and
        w.user_id is null;
```

Note this logic sort of assumes that you don't have duplicates in the `email` table with respect to `article_id`/`viewed_at`.

Comment: @Livewire . . . You accepted essentially the same answer posted 6 hours after this.

Comment: Hey @gordonlinoff sorry, I'm new to how the answer selection works. Could you briefly explain the etiquette? Sorry for any offense... none intended.